# При попытке скачать Django выдает ошибку

Tags: python, django

Я много чего пробовал но не получается. Я даже создал полностью новую папку и тоже ошыбка. Помогите[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "C:\Users\admin\Saved Games\Desktop\inkspace\bin\python.exe" - мсье знает толк в извращениях

Comment: Вроде если Вы сидите на Windows, Вы можете не указывать `pip3`, попробуйте просто `pip`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в пути, куда устанавливаете, избегать папок с русскими буквами и символами типа: _:., и т.п.

В идеале путь что-то вроде: D\django.